# Coding of servlet, which sends message to Websphere MQ 8 in wildfly AS 8

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq, wildfly-8

I confiqurated websphere mq in wildfly application server, as written

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Administration_and_Configuration_Guide/Deploy_the_WebSphere_MQ_Resource_Adapter.html

Now I want to write servlet, which will send message to queue MyTestQueue in queue manager JMSDEMO.

I don't understand, how I can to create jndi name of queue and connection factory in wildfly, which will match to connection factory and queue in my describe to resource adapter:

```
   <resource-adapter id="wmq.jmsra.rar">
        <archive>
            wmq.jmsra-8.0.0.4.rar
        </archive>
        <transaction-support>NoTransaction</transaction-support>
        <connection-definitions>
            <connection-definition class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl"
                    jndi-name="java:jboss/ConnectionFactoryToWB"
               enabled="true" 
                    pool-name="mqconn">
            <config-property name="port">
               1414
            </config-property>
                <config-property name="channel">
                    SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN
                </config-property>
                <config-property name="transportType">
                    BINDING
                </config-property>
                <config-property name="queueManager">
                    JMSDEMO
                </config-property>
            </connection-definition>
        </connection-definitions>
        <admin-objects>
            <admin-object 
                    class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.MQQueueProxy" 
                    jndi-name="java:jboss/testjcaq" 
                    pool-name="MQ.QUEUE.NAME">
                <config-property name="baseQueueName">
                    MyTestQueue
                </config-property>
            </admin-object>
        </admin-objects>
    </resource-adapter>
```

Help me please with this question.